# Assembly x86 "()" meaning

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

Im trying to get a rudimentary understanding of assembly language and I am having trouble with a couple of things and cant find an online source that makes sense to me.

What does the "leave" command do?

I know that:

(R)  = Mem[Reg[R]]

Where R is a register, but i don't know what the right part means. Is that dereferencing the register?

For the stack frame, will parameters always be negative?, local variables always be positive? and will the return address always be (4 + VAR1)?(VAR1 is the address of the first parameter)

Answer (score 0):

"leave" - this is an assembler directive used to go along with "enter" for assembly procedures.

Reg[R] - It's just register R, like si, esi, or rsi, but perhaps if you were looking at the instruction opcode, there's a bit field used to select a register, and if you called that bit field value R, then Reg[R] would mean the register selected by the bit field.

stack frame - this is optional. Some compilers have the option to not use stack frames. If stack frame is enabled, then the usual sequence at the start of a function is "push ebp", then "mov ebp,esp", so [esp] = the previous value of ebp, and ebp-offset is used to access parameters, and ebp+offset is used to get to access local variables. If frames are not used, then positive or zero offsets from esp are used for both parameters and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

`leave` is a one byte instruction that is equivalent to

```
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
```

in 32-bit mode.  In 16-bit or 64-bit mode, it's the same with 16-bit or 64-bit registers.